# How to get VVE (Vereniging van Eigenaars/Homeowner association) contact details in Holland?

Tags: netherlands, relocation, paperwork, legal, housing

I have bought a flat in Rotterdam. I have dealt with getting energy suppliers and other required stuff.

When I was signing the contract notary told me that I will be contacted by VVE (Vereniging van Eigenaars - local Homeowner Association) to pay fees for local repairs cleaning and such. However they never contacted me. Now it's been more than 3 months, and I am getting worried that I will get a hefty bill (of accumulated payments) and might also get into other legal trouble, due to some document getting lost or something…

**How can I get contact details of VvE?**

Comment: I can't tell from your question if that's what you are asking about but AFAIK, a VVE is specific to a given building/apartment complex. So I would look for signs in the hallway or ask your immediate neighbours. I would not be particularly concerned about the three months either, unless there is something big coming up, they must hold a meeting every year and that's the time I would expect to hear from them.

Comment: @Gala Hi Gala, yes that's the per building one I am talking about. I don't interact with any of my neighbors really (the kind of people you dont wan't to run into late at night). We do have postage board at the bottom but there's no info there, I have looked there already. Isn't there like a 'official' way to get in touch with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All VVEs must register themselves at the local Chamber of Commerce ("Kamer van Koophandel" or "KVK"). That doesn't mean that all of them do, but a block of flats probably has a registered VVE.

You can search for registered entitites at https://www.kvk.nl/orderstraat/bedrijf-kiezen/ . Try your street name and see if your flat comes up; most VVEs have names like "Vereniging van Eigenaren -some address number A to B-".

Then you buy a short extract ("Uittreksel") containing the address of the VVE and the names of the people currently running it (if they've kept it up to date) for "starting at" € 2.65. Then hopefully you can find them.

That's the formal way. But I would really ask the neighbours. Most people really aren't that bad when asked a simple question at a normal time of day,

Comment: Good morning Remco, I couldn't thank you enough. On  https://www.kvk.nl there was given VvE website (http://www.vvebeheer.net) for my my block of flats.